# HAProxy breaks dav .well-known redirects in NextCloud

Tags: redirect, haproxy, nextcloud

I have installed Nextcloud on a Homeserver tha5t also runs Plex. To rout connections from outside the network I am using HAProxy; it is correctly configured and works as expected.

In the process I had to change the Ports Nextcloud is Bind to with the following comand:

```
$ sudo snap set nextcloud ports.http=81 ports.https=444
```

which breaks the automatic rerouting for `/.well-known/caldav` and `/.well-known/carddav` and directly rerouts me to `https://nextcloud.domain.com:444/remote.php/dav/` which is inaccessable outside the LocalHost.

Because NextCloud handles its own SSL, this [approach](https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap/issues/1042#issuecomment-526813059) could not work becaues HAProxy cannot detect `/.well-known/caldav` and `/.well-known/carddav` on the request address.
I have been looking for the correct HAProxy configuration in the case of NextCloud handeling SSL but with no success so far. so I have decided to try and allow the Port `444` through the Firewall with this comand `$ sudo ufw allow from any to any port 444 proto tcp` and forwarded it through my Router to the Server. Theoretically I should be able to access `https://nextcloud.domain.com:444/remote.php/dav/` even from outside the network, but it only works on LocalHost. My thought is that (unless i forgot somthing) this Port is Blocked by the ISP and cannot be accessed from outside the Local Network. Now back to step 1 again to try and fix the redirecting problem:

Is there a way for HAProxy to catch `/.well-known/caldav` and `/.well-known/carddav` and do the correct redirecting to `https://nextcloud.domain.com/remote.php/dav/` if NextCloud is handeling its own SSL?

OR

Is there a way to edit the Path NextCloud automatically redirects to?
instead of `https://nextcloud.domain.com:444/remote.php/dav/` it should give `https://nextcloud.domain.com/remote.php/dav/`

Answer (score 0):

the only way to fix this is to let HAProxy manage the SSL.. there is no other way

Answer (score 0):

In addition to handing off SSL, the caldav/carddav redirects also need to be added to the frontend config:

```
acl caldav-endpoint path_beg /.well-known/caldav                                                   
http-request set-path /remote.php/dav if caldav-endpoint

acl carddav-endpoint path_beg /.well-known/carddav      
http-request set-path /remote.php/dav if carddav-endpoint
```

There is also some more info at the link below for pfSense HAProxy users:

https://help.nextcloud.com/t/well-known-caldav-and-carddav-with-haproxy/45155/3